# Preprocessor gating (Objective-)C code to only appear in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to conditionally include some code *only* when a header is imported to Swift, either through `import` or through a bridging header. Essentially, something similar to `__cplusplus` for C++.

Does this exist? I can only find people looking for a preprocessor equivalent *in* Swift, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `__swift__` definition, defined [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/719c4d9937bea0c0cfe5b17eb4cdf6c60fbba7c7/lib/ClangImporter/ClangImporter.cpp#L436):

```
languageVersion.preprocessorDefinition("__swift__", {10000, 100, 1})
```

In code:

```
#if __swift__
NS_INLINE BOOL IsThisSwift(void) { return YES; }
#else
NS_INLINE BOOL IsThisSwift(void) { return NO; }
#endif
```